# Verilog testbench error multiplex 4x1 using EDAPlayground

Tags: verilog, edaplayground

I'm doing a Multiplex 4x1 in Verilog using EDAPlayground, but I still get testbench errors, and I don't know why.

Here is one error:

> ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: and[_AND]." "design.sv"
> 26  6

```
module mux4x1(
  input x1, x2, x3, x4, s0, s1, 
  output f);
  wire s0_inv, out_x1, out_x2;
  wire s1_inv, out_x3, out_x4;
  wire out_mux1, out_mux2;
  wire out_mux3, out_mux4;
  
// mux2x1_1
  not (s1_inv, s1);
  and (out_x1, s1_inv, x1);
  and (out_x2, s1, x2);
  or (out_mux1, out_x1, out_x2);

// mux2x1_2
  not (s1_inv, s1);
  and (out_x3, s1_inv, x3);
  and (out_x4, s1, x4);
  or (out_mux2, out_x3, out_x4);
  
// mux4x1
  not (s0_inv, s0)
  and (out_mux3, s0_inv, out_mux1);
  and (out_mux4, s0_inv, out_mux2);
  or (f, out_mux3, out_mux4);
endmodule
```

Link: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/bkNc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to compile just your design code, I get this error:

```
  and (out_mux3, s0_inv, out_mux1);
    |
xmvlog: *E,EXPSMC : expecting a semicolon (';') [7.1(IEEE)].
```

Often this type of error is caused by the line of code **above** the reported line:

```
  not (s0_inv, s0)
```

Just add the semicolon:

```
  not (s0_inv, s0);
```

---

EDAplayground offers several different simulators, and some provide more helpful error messages than others.  You have it set for Aldec; switch to Cadence, for example, to see a different error message.